# -v option doesn't work in grep

Tags: regex, linux, bash, scripting, grep

Let's say the input is:

```
Something 
abcdefg
wordwordwordword
sjsjfifdsjifdsojs
```

I currently have this code: `grep --no-group-separator -A 1 "Something"`, which properly prints out

```
Something
abcdefg
```

But when I add -v to reverse the output (`grep --no-group-separator -vA 1 "Something"`), it out the whole input, including "Something" and "abcdefg", instead of just printing

```
wordwordwordword
sjsjfifdsjifdsojs
```

I've tried placing -v in different places, but it still didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean from reverse? `-v` option omits that specific line on which match has found. Please be clear about your question here and let us know on same.

Comment: Do you want to print line after a match us found `grep`??

Comment: Can't reproduce.  I get `abcdefg` `wordwordwordword` `something something`.

Comment: You want everything from the file except the results of the grep? Is that right?

Comment: I don't get it either; if I run this, it works find: `echo "Something 
abcdefg
wordwordwordword
sjsjfifdsjifdsojs" | grep --no-group-separator -A 1 -v "Something"`; maybe you actually use a different input than the one in your question?

Comment: @xor OP does not want the `abcdefg` that results. Essentially the stuff returned from `grep -A1 file` should be excluded from the results. (As i understand it)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like the following will do the trick:

```
grep -v "$(grep -A1 Something your_file)" your_file
```

Comment: Shouldn't `test` be `your_file`?

Comment: @Vasan  Fixed. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think what happens is the line before "something" does not match something. Hence the next line with "something" is printed as well. (because of the -A 1)